# ExtJS 4 - Rendering components that are initially hidden

Tags: layout, extjs, extjs4, hidden

One major difference that I have noticed between ExtJS 3.x and 4.x is how the rendering/layout calculation is handled for components that are rendered inside of a containing element that has display:none (NOT an Ext created/monitored containing element). In 3.x, upon showing the containing element, the Ext component it contained would be properly rendered and sized to whatever dimensions i set for it.

However, in 4.x, that same component will not be displayed at all and have a zero height and width when its containing element was shown. After it was visible if I do a call to .setSize() it would then properly be displayed. Problem is, in my application there is just no way to be able to go through all the events that could cause a hidden component to be shown, and add code to make sure its layout is manually forced to be recalculated.

So my question is, is there any way to get back 3.x's behavior in this situation for all components across the board in 4.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try to do is set up listeners on your components that [delegate](http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=itemclick) to the underlying DOM elements, perhaps that will solve your issue. 
However my suggestion is if at all possible is to use the framework to manage the entire page layout using Viewport.  You can still suck in the HTML (if you must) and render it inside containers or panels for example. Perfect use case here is Header and Footer which are generated by server side code (jsp, gsp, asp..) and then displayed in the North or South regions of the Viewport using `contentEl : 'myDivId'` configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately using the framework to manage the entire page layout is just not an option at this point for the application im working on. The event delegation idea is interesting though, however it seems like its a bit backwards.. since it would need to be the non-extjs elements notifying components that it contains that is now visible and that they should re-calculate their layout, right?

Comment: yep, that's the idea. Take a look at Saki's example I believe he is doing exactly that.